# not all parameters being send to fb like link post

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi i am trying to add facebook like button to my html email newsletter. i found this can only be done in a 2 click process. using this method:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?=$config['SITE_URL']?>Home  /newsletter_view.php?id=<?=$NewsLetterID?>&itemId=<?=$ItemRow->ID?>;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=80 target=">
   <img title="Facebook Like Button" src="<?=$config['SITE_URL'].'Images/like.png'?>"  alt="" />
</a>
```

in the link that i chose for the href i have id and item id . but when i click on this like button and takes me to the like.php page, and i click again on the like and see my post on facebook. i find that i liked the link with the parameter id only. item id is ommitted. why is that ?

and another thing, can we change how the like.php page looks like? it is kind of annoying being all empty and a like button on the top left corner only.can i open it as a popup ?

Answer (score 1):

> why is that ?

Because you forgot to **urlencode** your URL – which in this scenario is only a *parameter* inside of another link – properly.

Besides that, your whole a-element looks kinda messed up. Why is there `Home  /newsletter_view.php?` occuring *inside* the href attribute, and why is there `target=` at the end of it?

Are you sure you know at least the very basics of HTML syntax? Because to me, it looks like you don’t, not at all.

Comment: i know HTML basics .there is home/.... because this is the link i want them to like . and this is my page path. and i took this href syntax from http://emailexpert.org/adding-a-facebook-like-button-to-your-email-template/  ..changed only what he said i should change. thought this syntax should stay as it is for facebook .  thanks for ur answer anyway

Comment: „i know HTML basics” – that can hardly be true … your link would come out as something like <a href="http;//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=[...]>Home  /newsletter_view.php?id=123&itemId=456;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=80 target="> – and that doesn’t make sense at all. Everything between the first and the second " would be the content of your links href (so, basically _all_ of it) … and that can’t be what you want to achieve.